# Renumbering atoms in PDB using OpenBabel

Tags: proteins, docking, format-conversion

I'm trying to add polar hydrogens to protein (PDB ID 3l3l cleaned from water and ligands) and convert it to PDBQT using OpenBabel by:
`obabel -ipdb target.pdb -opdbqt -O target.pdbqt -xr --partialcharge gasteiger --addpolarh`
It's working well, but all hydrogens are appending to the end of file. I want to renumber atoms so that residues in PDB would go in increasing order and hydrogens were located "between" corresponding heavy atoms, like AutoDock Tools do this.

Is there a way to renumber them using OpenBabel? Or any other command-line utilities?

Comment: Try reopen in biopythown and save pdb  with preserve_atom_numbering = False

Comment: Please add a small bit of the pdb with non ordered H so that people can try to help you without having to spend too much time

Comment: See https://www.mail-archive.com/openbabel-discuss@lists.sourceforge.net/msg05790.html

Comment: I see the prob openbabel ( at least this one https://www.cheminfo.org/Chemistry/Cheminformatics/FormatConverter/index.html  OPEN BABEL 3.1.1) doesnt name the Hs correctly (their are all just H) so that biopython parser drops them as duplicates. Use pymol h_add to a pdb then save directly from pymol or run conversion in openbabel

Comment: mmmmh even my pymol assigns wrong names to H atoms compared to the ones in the https://www.ebi.ac.uk/pdbe-srv/pdbechem/ or http://ligand-expo.rcsb.org/ld-search.html

Comment: https://phenix-online.org/documentation/reference/ready_set.html ReadySet! is a program designed to prepare a PDB file for refinement as in ReadySet! Refine!!!. It will add hydrogens to the protein model using phenix.reduce and to the ligands using eLBOW. The appropriate restraints are also written to disk. Hydrogens can also be added to water molecules. Deuterium atoms can be added to facilitate dual xray-neutron refinement. Metal coordination files are also generated.

Comment: https://kpwulab.com/2021/02/19/pymolchimeraadd-hydrogens-to-your-structure/ chimera should work fine